# How to create a panel with support for Drag and Drop?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop

Suppose we have a ListBox with the Custom elements and the blank panel . When you drag these items to the panel , they must build on a certain logic. For example, if there's nothing panel , the element is located in the middle. But if there is , then the new element is to stay near the element that is closest to it . As such it is possible to implement?

For example:

[image]

Comment: This sounds more like layout problem than something to do with drag-n-drop. Could you present it better (with screenshot)?

Comment: @Sinatr, For example https://gyazo.com/4d3ea832eb937abc1f3ce0f1e9979157

Comment: Example is not really clear, but the picture looks like you want to distinguish near which edge of existing item new item was dropped. Right? One possibility is to determine position (search for questions asking for drag-n-drop within `Canvas`, e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21833168/1997232)) and have position also stored in item ViewModel, then you can use those to determine whenever add new item on top or on the right side. Another is to make new item also accepting drag and drop (item view should create *hot-spot* areas accepting drag-n-drop).

Comment: Yes, it's possible to implement it.  Has nothing to do with MVVM, as it's solely a UI concern.  You'll need a custom control and lots of code in the background.  Come back if you have any problems implementing it.

Comment: @Will, I do not know where to start at all.

Comment: Yeah, I know this.  You won't find your solution in an answer here.  You'll find it in a book.  Or by hiring a developer.  UI development ***is hard***.

Answer (score 0):

I modified [this answer](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/16591975/c-sharp-drag-and-drop-from-listbox#16596174) of working drag and drop implementation by adding some sorting logic. Placing an item in the middle visually can be done with CSS styling.

Assumption: "closest to it" means closest alphabetically.

```
public object lb_item = null;

private void listBox1_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;

    lb_item = lb.SelectedItem;
    lb.Items.Remove(lb.SelectedItem);
}

private void listBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{       
    if (lb_item != null)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(lb_item);
        lb_item = null;

        // Here I added the logic:
        // Sort all items added previously 
        // (thereby placing item in the middle).
        listBox1.Sorted = true;
    }
}


private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lb_item = null;

    if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }                

    int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
    string s = listBox1.Items[index].ToString();
    DragDropEffects dde1 = DoDragDrop(s, DragDropEffects.All);      
}

private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{            
    lb_item = null;
}
```